# Concurrency with GraphDiff when adding different child objects to owned collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, graphdiff

to make things not too complex, I will not take my own entity model for this question but the one from the original GraphDiff-Blog-Post [here](http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/) where there is a company entity that has multiple contacts. To illustrate my problem I think this is more than enough.

So basically my code is the same as in the graphdiff example, which works fine:

```
using (var context = new TestDbContext())  
{
    // Update the company and state that the company 'owns' the collection Contacts.
    context.UpdateGraph(company, map => map
        .OwnedCollection(p => p.Contacts)
    );

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem is when trying to add new contacts to the same company on 2 different instances of the program. For example, Instance 1 saves a new Contact A, afterwards Instance 2 saves a new Contact B. The Graph from Instance 1 gets updated in the DB just fine, but the graph from Instance 2 overrides all the changes that Instance 1 made and deletes the newly created Contact A.

Is there a way to solve this problem with Graphdiff? Maybe I need to make 2 indipendent updates(one for company and one for contacts), but using GraphDiff in the first place wouldn't make much sense anymore. Also thought about making a diff before updating the graph, but that seems pretty overkill as well.

Or maybe I'm just to unexperienced with entity framework all together to see the easy solution : )

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: the context is not (and can not be) thread-safe. That means you'll have to make sure your DbContext is up-to-date when calling SaveChanges() (if you don't, you'll always run into this problem). You should probably change the method to get the current graph right before saving, which will lower the probability of this occuring, or not let programs call these functions asynchronously.

Comment: Is this really a problem with the context not being thread safe? As I understand, it's simply a matter of Instance 2 seeing that there is a new strange Contact A that he doesn't know, so Contact A gets deleteted to be in sync with the saved graph (there is a sql delete executed on the db).

Comment: EF will check for concurrency upon calling SaveChanges(). As the EntityStates of any not ambient context do not have to be consistent over the whole program, the results will not be as expected, which will result in an exception being thrown.